# Refresh long-lived token via Instagram graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have long-lived token of user on back-end and successfully getting different information from graph-api endpoints.

Now I am trying to refresh these valid, unexpired tokens on my side periodically and following [Refresh Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/refresh_access_token#reading) documentation, but getting an error with 400 status code every time:

My request:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://graph.instagram.com/refresh_access_token?grant_type=ig_refresh_token&&access_token={my_token}'
```

Response:

```
Sorry, this content isn't available right now
```

To make sure that token was valid, checked it via [Access Token Debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) and it seems that my token is valid for next 3 months.

I found that several other engineers having the same problem but was not able to find any way out or the reason of this issue.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: I am in the same boat. Did you found out a solution to this ?

Comment: @AngleV yep, I have found it and just posted it as an answer. Hope it helps you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer on my question and since I already see one person in comment, for whom my answer will be useful, going to post it here.

In order to refresh valid token, we can use `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` endpoint.
So the request with params will be like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=fb_exchange_token
&client_id={client-id}
&client_secret={client_secret}
&exchange_token={old_token}
```

Also, one more note - if I remember correctly, even old token will keep valid until its ttl don't expires.

Comment: Your solution does not seems to work.

My purpose is to refresh the long-lived token of instagram, that is going to expire in 60 days.

The workflow is :

User sign in to his account and grant permission to my app.
After that i get the short lived token and i exchange it with long lived token which has 2 months expiration.
The request is how can we refresh this long-lived token with a new one so that nevers expires?

Comment: You can't generate the token which never expires. It would be super unsecure in any case. 
Rather you can use the long lived token to generate the new one. Let's say if it lives for 2 month, let's create the job which crates new token from existing one and run that job in every 7 week.

Comment: We just want to refresh it, as described in the documentation, not to generate a new one. I can generate new one, without using the old one. Why to bother with this when I need to edit my config files to change the key every 2 months?